# How to know the jenkins version supported by a plugin

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins version is 2.222.1
I want users to be able to login and upload file to Jenkins using job. For that I tried installing the `file parameter` plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters

But the install page shows latest version of file parameter is not supported for Jenkins version 2.222.1
[image]

From the plugin release page there are older versions available. How can I know the support matrix, i.e. which file parameter plugin is supported for the Jenkins version I have?

Answer (score 1):

The web page you linked for the file parameter plugin shows the version requirements:

> Requires Jenkins 2.289.1

Also, if you download the plugin, the file META-INF/maven/io.jenkins.plugins/file-parameters/pom.xml lists all the dependencies, including the version of Jenkins as well as versions of other plugins.